# Regular Expression : Complex Multiple Matches

Tags: python, regex

```
line = 'bla bla bla Tax_Id=9606 Gene_Symbol=OR4F16 OR4F28P OR4F29 OR4F2P OR4F3 DTR4F7P BPFR4F8P Gene_Accession=ENSG00000217874 bla bla bla'
```

I am trying to match all the Gene symbols. I tried using re, regex and their different modules but it doesn't work.

Comment: How did you  try it?

Comment: There are many who might like to offer help, David. You are going to have to be more explicit about what you want to do. You also need to show what code you have written to solve the problem using, say, the re module.

Comment: `but it doesn't work` Regex works !

Answer (score 0):

this works assuming Gene_Symbol and Gene_Accession are always in the order of you example. Otherwise the regular expression would need to be tweaked.

```
import re

line = 'bla bla bla Tax_Id=9606 Gene_Symbol=OR4F16 OR4F28P OR4F29 OR4F2P OR4F3 DTR4F7P BPFR4F8P Gene_Accession=ENSG00000217874 bla bla bla'

regex = r"Gene_Symbol=(.*)Gene_Accession"

p = re.search(regex,line)

symbols = p.group(1).split()

for symbol in symbols:
    print symbol
```

output:

```
OR4F16
OR4F28P
OR4F29
OR4F2P
OR4F3
DTR4F7P
BPFR4F8P
```